# Set RibbonButton Style as it would be clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I have a few default `RibbonButton`s:

```
<RibbonButton x:Name="MouseModeButton" Label="Maus" Click="MouseModeButton_Click"
              LargeImageSource="/Images/MainWindow/Mouse.png" />
<RibbonButton x:Name="MarkModeButton" Label="Markieren" Click="MarkModeButton_Click"
              LargeImageSource="/Images/MainWindow/Mark.png" />
```

These buttons are "modes" where only one (the last clicked) is enabled.
I want this enabled `RibbonButton` to be highlighted from the other ones - the best thing I could come up with is to set the style as it would be clicked right now.

I tried to google it, but the world of WPF seemd to be abadoned from good googleable solutions in xaml. So how would I set this programmaticly from code behind, when a button is clicked, the style should be like the moment when it is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`RibbonRadioButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ff703178(v=vs.100)) instead, it does exactly what you want.

```
<RibbonRadioButton x:Name="MouseModeButton" Label="Maus" Click="MouseModeButton_Click"
                   LargeImageSource="/Images/MainWindow/Mouse.png" />
<RibbonRadioButton x:Name="MarkModeButton" Label="Markieren" Click="MarkModeButton_Click"
                   LargeImageSource="/Images/MainWindow/Mark.png" />
```

You can define mutually exclusive button groups using the [`GroupName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton.GroupName);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) property, e.g.:

```
<Ribbon>
   <RibbonTab Header="tab">
      <RibbonGroup Header="Sample">
         <RibbonRadioButton Label="Group 1 - Button 1" GroupName="Group 1"/>
         <RibbonRadioButton Label="Group 1 - Button 2" GroupName="Group 1"/>
         <RibbonRadioButton Label="Group 1 - Button 3" GroupName="Group 1"/>
         <RibbonRadioButton Label="Group 2 - Button 1" GroupName="Group 2"/>
         <RibbonRadioButton Label="Group 2 - Button 2" GroupName="Group 2"/>
         <RibbonRadioButton Label="Group 2 - Button 3" GroupName="Group 2"/>
      </RibbonGroup>
   </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```